# Can you make the scope inherit to a child page?

Tags: angularjs

I have a url-structure that looks like this:

```
    when('/:location',{
        controller: 'locationController',
        templateUrl: 'partials/single.html',
    }).
    when('/:location/karta',{
        redirectTo: '/:location/karta/CYKLING'
    }).
    when('/:location/karta/:type',{
        templateUrl: 'partials/directions.html'
    }).
```

and the following controllers:

```
controller('locationController', function($scope, $location, $routeParams, instagram, swimlocations) {
        $scope.name = $routeParams.location;
        $scope.location = swimlocations.getLocation($routeParams.location)
        instagram.getPhotosByLocation($scope.location.long,$scope.location.lat, 100, function(data){
            $scope.images = data;
        });
}).
controller('directionController'. function($scope, $location, $routeParams, swimlocations) {
    $scope.name = $routeParams.location;
        $scope.location = swimlocations.getLocation($routeParams.location)  
}).
```

As you can see, the two controllers are as good as identical, apart from the first one making a request to instagram. Is there any way to avoid this code-duplication?

Answer (score 0):

Angular Is Having "Module" Concept ... 
You Need To Have A Module Kind Of Structure That Will Make All Resources Available To Child Controllers.

For Example See 2nd Last Example On Angularjs.org .. They Have Used Module.

It should Help.

Let Me Know If It helps..

Comment: what's the name of the example?

Comment: Actually My net Is Slow...not Able To jsfiddle....Name = Wire up a Backend ....In Front Of Website

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs you can put common functionality into a prototype and use that for your controllers. See [ngController docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) for the use of prototypes (the example doesn't use inheritance, though).

Another solution is to listen to location events in the parent scope and set the properties there. See the [$location docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24location) for the events.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with $rootScope functions ( maybe not the perfect way but it's easy):

add this after your module/config that you showed us for routing.

```
when('/:location',{
        controller: 'locationController',
        templateUrl: 'partials/single.html',
    }).
    when('/:location/karta',{
        redirectTo: '/:location/karta/CYKLING'
    }).
    when('/:location/karta/:type',{
        templateUrl: 'partials/directions.html' // doesnt this need a controller to be caled?
    })
    .run(function($rootScope) {

        $rootScope.var = null; //global variable


    $rootScope.globalFoo = function(variable) {
        alert("I'm global function with variable! " + variable);
    }; // you can make your function here and make an IF to check what kind of calls u   need to make

$rootScope.globalFooReturn = function(variable) {
        return "I'm global function with variable! " + variable;
    };
```

Then add $rootScope to your controller and just call the function to trigger it:

```
controller('locationController', function($rootScope, $scope, $location, 
$routeParams, instagram, swimlocations){

$rootScope.globalFoo("Instagram");

$scope.message = $rootScope.globalFooReturn("Instagram");
alert($scope.message);

//or
alert($rootScope.globalFooReturn("Instagram"));


}
```